# {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"} in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I am  having a photo upload scenario where when I click on link, it has to goto Instagram and upload pictures from there. But I am facing the following issue:

> {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message":
>   "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

This is the redirected url when I click on link :

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/instagram/callback/?edit=&response_type=code
```

This is my code:

routes.rb:

```
get "/instagram/callback" => "photos#instagram_callback"
```

photos_controller:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_for_errors, :only => [:instagram_callback]
  def instagram_callback
    response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => Rails.application.config.custom.domain_url + 'instagram/callback/?edit=' + (params[:edit].present? ? params[:edit] : ''))
    oauth = OauthAccessToken.find_or_create_by_provider_and_user_id('instagram', current_user.id)
    oauth.access_token = response.access_token
    oauth.save
    if params[:edit].present?
      redirect_to edit_user_report_path(current_user, params[:edit], :ig => true)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_report_path(current_user, :ig => true)
    end
  end
end
```

views/_photos.html.erb:

```
<% if @instagram_oauth.nil? %>
  <%= link_to '', Instagram.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => Rails.application.config.custom.domain_url + 'instagram/callback/?edit=' + (params[:id].present? ? params[:id] : ''))%>
<% end %>
```

Please help.

Comment: what is the redirect uri you set in instagarm

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your redirect_uri "http://localhost:3000/instagram/callback/" for your application on [instagram developer portal](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)
[More information](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) about redirect_uri

Answer (score 0):

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Calls have to be made over https. Not sure they would cause this error but you show http in your instagram url.